# Why can't Windows 7 see my virtual storage devices in KVM?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, qemu, kvm-switch

I'm trying to install Windows 7 inside of kvm on Ubuntu 10.04. Previously I've installed guest Windows XP and guest Ubuntu without incident. However, when I tried to install Windows 7, this happened:

First, multiple CPUs caused a blue-screen. That's fine, I guess I'll only have 1 cpu.

Then, I come across another problem. Windows can't see my virtual HDD. It asks me to insert a driver CD. I've downloaded this [Red Hat Virtio driver](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Windows7Install) and tried to use that. Windows recognizes it's a driver, but after I select it, it says it didn't find any new hardware using that driver*. Of course for that last one, I added a Virtio HDD instead of the IDE HDD, but no luck.

*I get

```
No new devices could be found. Make sure the driver files are correct and located on the driver installation media.
```

Has anyone successfully installed win7 and if so, did you encounter this problem and find a work-around?

I have kvm version:

```
$ kvm --version
QEMU PC emulator version 0.12.3 (qemu-kvm-0.12.3), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
$ modinfo kvm
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-35-server/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Qumranet
srcversion:     FC0D2EE344D3C88A41BA5A4
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.32-35-server SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           oos_shadow:bool
parm:           ignore_msrs:bool
$ modinfo kvm_intel
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-35-server/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Qumranet
srcversion:     5C339EB72FC5D22420654DC
depends:        kvm
vermagic:       2.6.32-35-server SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bypass_guest_pf:bool
parm:           vpid:bool
parm:           flexpriority:bool
parm:           ept:bool
parm:           unrestricted_guest:bool
parm:           emulate_invalid_guest_state:bool
parm:           ple_gap:int
parm:           ple_window:int
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not presonlly used KVM, however I have exlerience with several other virtual machines.  The last time I had issues with installing an os in the virtual machine, it turned out to be a version issue. Verify the virtual machine, and version you are using is compatible with Win7.   Your virtual machine seems tio pre-Win7.  Try upgrading your KVM.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check, but I tried to add to the question what version I have.... Does that help?

Comment: The version of KVM you're using is getting close to two years old -- 0.12.3 was released in February 2010. Upgrading is likely to solve your problems.

Comment: Okay, I am cloning [kvm](git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/virt/kvm/kvm.git) and then I plan on doing `make` and `make install`... That's what you're suggesting, right?